# Having error messages in my new activity in my android app

Tags: android

I just created a new activity called "activity_direction" in my android app,but I discovered an error message in two lines of my new activity. First one is on `setContentView(R.layout.activity_direction);` of the `onCreate()` method.The error message says:

`"activity_direction cannot be resolved to a type or is not a field".`

The second error message is at `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.direction, menu);` of the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.The error message also says:

```
"activity_direction cannot be resolved to a type or is not a field".
```

Comment: Have you created `activity_direction.xml` under `res/layout` directory?

Comment: post your xml file .

Comment: You have to select R.layout of your project not inbuild library, by pressing ctrl+space you get to know.

Answer (score 0):

Select project from menu options in eclipse and click build project.
This issue mey occure when R.java file does could not create id for layout. if problem still remain, just restart your eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already created activity_direction.xml under res/layout directory and direction.xml under res/menu. Try this.

In Eclipse,
Select **Project -> Clean**

In Android Studio,
Select **Build -> Clean Project**

Comment: @uzo : Please find time to tick, if the solution works. Thanks.